# How to implement server side blazor Custom Authorization Provider Correctly

Tags: c#, blazor, claims-based-identity, blazor-server-side, iprincipal

I am trying to implement a basic custom Auth provider in my server side blazor project, but I am having some difficulty implementing the 'IsAuthenticating' property correctly.

I used this site as my starter point, but it throws an error if '`IsAuthenticating`' is set to true (more specifically when I return null from `GetAuthenticationStateAsync()`). https://gunnarpeipman.com/client-side-blazor-authorizeview/.

Specifically this line of code:

```
if(IsAuthenticating)
    {
        return null; <---- This line throws error
    }
    else if(IsAuthenticated)
    {
        identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "TestUser")

                    }, "WebApiAuth");
    }
    else
    {
        identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
    }
```

The exact error thrown is:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync()
```

I did not want to clutter with stack trace.

Can this be achieved, and if so how?

Comment: The latest preview (3.2.0 Preview 2) supports this 'out of the box'. Review that first. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/

Comment: Thanks for the link I will review.

Comment: I missed that 'server-side'. That makes your question an odd one, but not impossible. Do note that the template solution relies on the ASP.NET cookie, you'll have to think about using or replacing that.

Comment: I have been reviewing the link you provided, and even installed the template you suggested. Still processing all the information and trying to find a way to utilize the webassembly blazor as I need. I have a unique requirement to utilize jwt tokens with windows authentication. IE. My api endpoint to retrieve token is windows auth, but returns a token to be used in client applications that may be on the public network or private network. I appreciate the simple link. I believe I have been incorrect to utilize server side blazor for client application.