# There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider'

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

While trying to find an answer to this question here: [How to implement server side blazor Custom Authorization Provider Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60624778/how-to-implement-server-side-blazor-custom-authorization-provider-correctly) I have encountered a new error, that I am unsure how to resolve. Taking the template from @Henk Holterman's comment here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/ I have been trying to develop some understanding how to implement web assembly blazor & server-side blazor, and the differences between the two.

Locally I can run my project and everything works as expected, I can login register and authorize a user. Once I deploy my application to IIS I start to receive WASM errors in console regarding no registered service 'AuthenticationStateProvider'.

When I first deployed my application to IIS I also had issues with the appsettings.json file regarding the IdentityServer section, and I am wondering if I have broken something. The only section that I added was the "Key" section because I was receiving errors for no key filename defined. Which lead me to a stackoverflow post here: [IdentityServer4 not working in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094788/identityserver4-not-working-in-production)
 to help resolve by exporting ssl cert to use as a file, which I then included in my project directory on IIS.

server-side appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-BlazorApp3.Server-A7F1C813-7F5D-4B96-8663-B8FA2E1472E8;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
   "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "BlazorApp3.Client": {
      "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
    }
   },
   "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "CertName.pfx",
      "Password": "CertPassword"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

server-side blazor startup.cs
I have included app.UsePathBase("client-side-blazor") here because in IIS my application is not at the root node. It is a sub node of a site.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLogging();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UsePathBase("/client-side-blazor");

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
```

client-side webassembly blazor program.cs

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        builder.Services.AddBaseAddressHttpClient();

        //builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

        builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
```

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore() is commented out above, been trying to follow some other SO posts regarding my current issue.

client blazor index.html

```
<base href="/client-side-blazor/"/>
```

As a side note, it is still a little unclear what project to publish when creating a web assembly blazor project. In the references the server-side project has the client dll which makes my think that I should publish the server project, but I'm understanding from documentation that I could also deploy/publish just the web assembly project by itself (maybe as a stand alone project with no Authentication/Authorization). Any extra useful information that is easy to swallow would be greatly appreciated.

Links I have used thus far in my research:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: did you add the js script in your index.html : [Index page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-3.1#index-page)

Comment: Publishing: you need to publish the server project, it contains the client app

Comment: Ok. Thats what I thought.  Also yes, the js file gives 200 result.

Comment: Did you upgrade to 3.2.0-preview2.20160.5 and follow : [Upgrade an existing project](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/)

Comment: Did you add a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication package ?

Comment: No I did not upgrade any project. I downloaded web assembly blazor template from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/ , created a new project, change connection string to a local database, and updated projects to use new base path 'client-side-server'. I already have a server-side blazor project that works seperate from this, but I am trying to re-create it using web assembly blazor.

Comment: strangely enough, I decided to delete the .vs folder and reload project and I do not receive error anymore, but now dealing with another issue altogether. I can log in locally but Authorize fails with a 401. Either I'm doing something completly wrong or web assembly blazor is incomplete.

Comment: to answer your question above, yes Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication is included in client project -v 3.2.0-preview2.20160.5

Comment: I don't think it work with base href other than /

Comment: That's my thoughts as well at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I thought I would try a couple things here. and wanted to show what I found without cluttering comments.

Adding services.AddAuthorizationCore() to startup.cs (and delete the .vs folder and reload project) in server-side blazor answers this SO post, but introduces a new problem. My question then is, is this really necessary to have in server-side blazor project because the site I was following did not add it. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/

Secondly I believe the real issue is when I changed the base href tag. If I create a new project, change the connection string and run it, everything is good. If I then stop the application, change the

```
<base href="/client-side-blazor/"/>
```

(including trailing slash) in index.html and add

```
app.UsePathBase("/client-side-blazor")
```

to server-side blazor startup.cs, and then rerun the application it no longer works as before. and calls to the weather forcast controller responds with 401.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test yet, but supposedly this is fixed. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19928

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue with this :

```
 services.AddScoped<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
 services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(s => s.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>());
```

Answer (score -3):

To resolve this issue, I closed the project, deleted the "obj" folder, reloaded the project and all was well.

H/T to John Dover as his answer led me to remember that pesky folder.